# Pass JSON file to a Java AWS Lambda Function via API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am testing a bit with AWS lambda functions and API Gateway and by now, I can not answer the following question to myself:
What is the best practice to parse a JSON Body of a Request via an AWS API Gateway to a Lambda Function?

I have written several Request Handlers, that parse a JSON Input using a map of String or even a default Java Class. This works quiet well when testing it and just passing the JSON definition to my Lambda function. But when it comes to the part, where I am using curl, the JSON data is, of course, in the request body and my Function is not extracting it. So I am wondering, what is the best way to parse JSON data that is in a Request Body via a Java Method?

Is there a way to just pass the body through the AWS API Gateway? Or do I just have to use an inputStream in my Java Method and extract the JSON data on my own?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, try using Postman and configure it to pass JSON to the API Gateway endpoint. The API Gateway endpoint passes the JSON to the Lambda function. So in my example here, I have configured an API Gateway endpoint that accepts a PUT request and accepts JSON that specifies a file name.

The Lambda function generates a presigned URL and returns it, as shown at bottom of screen shot.

See Postman sending the request:

[image]

The Lambda function gets the value like this within the Lambda handler. No need for input streams or anything like that. Notice the string value you specify within **event.get()** matches the value in JSON.

```
public class UploadHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> event, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        String fileName = event.get("filename");

...
```

Of course, you have to setup your API gateway endpoint to use that specific Lambda function. Once you do - you can make requests, pass the JSON and the Lambda function can get the value(s).